# Pitfalls of maximizing the likelihood

Tags: statistical-significance, estimation, maximum-likelihood

I have some data (y, X) of length N and covariate matrix X has 2 columns. I know my true model is y = 10 + X1 + noise, so my true beta is [1, 0], one covariate is irrelevant. I now want to estimate this using maximum likelihood using a Normal/Gaussian distribution.

I minimize the negative log likelihood `sum(log(L(y|a + beta X, sigma)))` using some gradient based optimizer.

1. Sometimes I find that my beta estimate is shrunk to 0 and `a` goes to the mean of y. Which is kind of a probable model but not the truth.
2. I also find that the estimates of the 2 betas are correlated during optimisation, but they shouldn't be, since only one X matters. I find that irrelevant covariate has a non zero beta.
3. I also assume that if sigma were very large, all estimates would kind of fall within the mu +- sigma range. So there might be a risk sigma is over-estimated.

Any ideas how to avoid these issues?

Comment: How exactly do you create this data? Are $X_1$ and $X_2$ correlated by chance?

Comment: Hi: When you simulate $y$, did you generate noise that was normally distributed ?

Comment: Yes both X are IID, and the noise is also IID Normal

Comment: Would you give a specific set of X values and the variance of the noise so that we can construct a reproduceable example?  And it does matter if you're fixing on a specific set of the irrelevant covariate values or if those irrelevant covariate values are random each time.